# Scraper: Adding Delay between Iterations

Tags: python, scrapy, delay

For a scraping project, I want to add a 1 second delay between each iteration of the script. In other threads, I have already read that a delay can be included through the "time" feature.

However, the code below is despite the inclusion of "time" still processing multiple requests per second, which is simply too fast for the scraper. Does anyone know how to make the 1 second delay work properly?

```
import scrapy
import time

custom_settings = {
'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,
'USER_AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1"
}

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider1'
    allowed_domains = ['google.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.google.com/search?q=Activision&biw=1280&bih=607&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A01%2F01%2F2004%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2004&tbm=nws',
                  'https://www.google.com/search?q=Activision&biw=1280&bih=607&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A01%2F01%2F2005%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2005&tbm=nws',
                  'https://www.google.com/search?q=Activision&biw=1280&bih=607&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A01%2F01%2F2006%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2006&tbm=nws',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = {
            'results': response.css('#resultStats::text')[0].extract(),
            'url': response.url,
        }
        yield item
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You'll need to post your full code, no where is your `parse` method called

Comment: That is the full code already. I am adding the rest manually in the terminal by using -o filename.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special setting for that, called download-delay

You can read more in docs for scrapy: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay